# Python store list index issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am learning Python and I have created a little program to monitor blood sugar levels.

I begin to read in how many times the sugar levels will be measured. Then I check if it's too low, too high or normal.

In the print statement I also put in the index simulating days. Finally I show which day it was highest and lowest and the average blood sugar level.

My issue is that I haven't managed to use the dynamic index nr to show as the "day" in the print statement of the highest and lowest blood sugar.

This is my code, I have put empty `{}` in my two min and max print statements as placeholders:

```
from numpy import mean


def bloodSugar():
    sugarLevel = []

    occour = int(input("Input amount of days you want to measure you blood sugar : "))
    print("------------------------------------------------------------\n")

    for i in range(0, occour):
        value = float(input("Input blood sugar level: "))
        print("\n")
        sugarLevel.append(value)

    for value in sugarLevel:
        index = sugarLevel.index(value)
        if value < 5:
            print(
                f"Your blood sugar: {value} is too low!!! under day {index+1}\n")
        elif value > 10:
            print(
                f"Your blood sugar: {value} is too high!!! under day {index+1}\n")
        else:
            print(f"Your blood sugar: {value} is normal under day {index+1}\n")

    avg = mean(sugarLevel)
    print(f"Highest blood sugar {max(sugarLevel)} was under day {}")
    print(f"Lowest blood sugar {min(sugarLevel)} was under day {}")
    print(f"Average blood sugar {round(avg,2)} under {occour} days")


bloodSugar()
```

What am I missing out? Maybe store the index under highest and lowest day variables?

Comment: you can look at `enumerate` like this `max(enumerate(sugarLevel))` it will return a tuple `(index, value)`

Comment: Look at 'enumerate'

Comment: Change for loop to `for index, value in enumerate(sugarLevel)` which gives index and value for each item in sugarLevel.  Remove `index = sugarLevel.index(value)`.

Comment: for your info you can also find the min and max values in the same for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the index of the max/min sugar level values just like you found the sugar level index for everyday values:

```
    index = 0
    for value in sugarLevel:
        index += 1
        if value < 5:
            print(
                f"Your blood sugar: {value} is too low!!! under day {index}\n")
        elif value > 10:
            print(
                f"Your blood sugar: {value} is too high!!! under day {index}\n")
        else:
            print(f"Your blood sugar: {value} is normal under day {index}\n")

    avg = mean(sugarLevel)
    print(f"Highest blood sugar {max(sugarLevel)} was under day {sugarLevel.index(max(sugarLevel)) + 1}")
    print(f"Lowest blood sugar {min(sugarLevel)} was under day {sugarLevel.index(min(sugarLevel)) + 1}")
    print(f"Average blood sugar {round(avg, 2)} under {occour} days")
```